# Differences or similarities between Segmented paging and Paged segmentation?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging, memory-segmentation

I was studying combined paging/segmentation systems and in my book there were two approaches to this :

```
1.paged segmentation
2.segmented paging
```

I could not make out the difference between the two. I think in paged segmentation the segment is divided into pages and in segmented paging the pages are divided into segments, though I don't know if I am right or wrong. Meanwhile on the internet the combined paging/segmentation is described using one scheme only. I can't figure out why in my coursebook there are two schemes for this. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure (because I've never heard of segmented paging), but dividing pages into segments doesn't really make any sense since the whole idea of pages is that they are the smallest piece of memory that can be paged in or out in a paged system. Needless to say, it is not used very much :). I believe your interpretation of paged segmentation is correct, though.

Comment: Do you mean "Segmentation" and "Paging"?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

So,after vigorously searching on net for the difference or similarity between these two terms,I have come up on a final answer.First of all I would write down the **similarities:**

- They both (segmented paging and paged segmentation) are a type of paging/segmentation combined systems (Paging and Segmentation can be combined by dividing each segment into pages).
- In both the system the segments are divided into pages.

Now to describe the **differences** I will have to define and describe each term separately:

- **Segmented paging-** Segments are divided into pages.Implementation requires STR(segment table register) and PMT(page map table).In this scheme, each virtual address consists of a *segment number*, *page number* within that segment and an *offset* within that page.The segment number indexes into segment table which yields the base address of the page table for that segment.The page number indexes into the page table,each of which entry is a page frame.Adding the PFN(page frame number) and the offset results in the physical address.Hence addressing can be described by the following function :

> **va = (s,p,w)** where, va is the virtual address, |s| determines number of
>   segments (size of ST), |p| determines number of pages per segment (size of
>   PT), |w| determines page size.

```
address_map(s, p, w)
{
pa = *(*(STR+s)+p)+w;
return pa;
}
```

The diagram is here:

[image: Segmented Paging]

- **Paged Segmentation**- Sometimes segment table or page table may too large to keep in physical memory(they can even reach MBs).Therefore,the segment table is divided into pages too and thus a page table of ST pages is created. The *segment number* is broken into *page no.(s1)* and *page offset(s2)* of page table of ST pages.So,the virtual address can be described as :

**va = (s1,s2,p,w)**

```
address_map
(s1, s2, p, w)
{
pa = *(*(*(STR+s1)+s2)+p)+w;
return pa;
}
```

The diagram description is here:
[image: Paged Segmentation]

Comment: Will like to know the source of this information as it somewhat differs from what is said [here](http://nob.cs.ucdavis.edu/classes/ecs150-2008-02/handouts/memory/mm-segpag.html)

Comment: hey @0decimal0, in segmented paging diagram, should segment tables be replaced by segment table ?

Answer (score 8):

### Best characteristics of paging

The fact is, paging has the following goodies:

1. Fast Allocation (At least faster than segmentation)
2. No External Fragmentation(The last page in this method suffers from **Internal Fragmentation**)

### Best characteristics of segmentation

But there is also a great behavior seen from segmentation:

1. Sharing
2. Protection

The given terms, can be combined and create the following terms:

- **Segmented Paging**: The virtual address space is divided into segments. The physical address space is divided into page frames.
- **Paged Segmentation**: The main **Segmentation Technique** which uses the process segment table sometimes goes out of bound! Meaning that the size gets too large and the main memory does not have enough space to keep the segment table. Therefore the segment table and the segment number is divided into pages.

### Requirements for the Segmented Paging

There are multiple steps need to be taken to achieve the Segmented Paging:

1. Each segment table entry represents a page table base address.
2. STR(Segment Table Register) and PMT(Page Map Table) are filled with desired values.
3. Each virtual address consists of a **Segment Number**, **Page Number** and the **Offset** within that page.
4. The segment number indexes into the segment table which gives us the the **base address** of the **page table** for that segment.
5. The page number indexes into the page table.
6. Each page table entry is a **page frame**.
7. Final result which is a **Physical Address** is found by adding the **page frame number** and the **offset**.

### Requirements for the Paged segmentation

The following steps take place in this scheme:

1. Each segment entry is divided into multiple segments.
2. For each segment table entry, which represents a gathering of the pages, a page table is created.

Answer (score 3):

**Segmentation leads to slower page translations and swapping**

For those reasons, segmentation was largely dropped on x86-64.

The main difference between them is that:

- paging splits memory into fixed sized chunks
- segmentation allows different widths for each chunk

While it might appear smarter to have configurable segment widths, as you increase memory size for a process, fragmentation is inevitable, e.g.:

```
|   | process 1 |       | process 2 |                        |
     -----------         -----------
0                                                            max
```

will eventually become as process 1 grows:

```
|   | process 1        || process 2 |                        |
     ------------------  -------------
0                                                            max
```

until a split is inevitable:

```
|   | process 1 part 1 || process 2 |   | process 1 part 2 | |
     ------------------  -----------     ------------------
0                                                            max
```

At this point:

- the only way to translate pages is to do binary searches over all pages of process 1, which takes an unacceptable log(n)
- a swap out of process 1 part 1 could be huge since that segment could be huge

With fixed sized pages however:

- every 32-bit translation does only 2 memory reads: directory and page table walk
- every swap is an acceptable 4KiB

Fixed sized chunks of memory are simply more manageable, and have dominated current OS design.

See also: [How does x86 paging work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431261/how-does-x86-paging-work)