# Linux uses Paging or Segmentation or Both?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

After studying about Segmentation and Paging .Both have there pros and cons.
So what do we use Paging or Segmentation or Both together ???

(Linux/Windows) uses Paging or Segmentation or Both ????

Comment: See: [**Segmentation in Linux : Segmentation & Paging are redundant?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029064/segmentation-in-linux-segmentation-paging-are-redundant)